# Passing List<String> from C# to native COM interface

Tags: c#, c++, com, idl

I'm doing some prototyping, plugging into a big legacy C++ application. I'm using C# to do this as a proof of concept (eventually I will write the library in C++). I've setup a COM interface between my C++ application and a .net class library and am able to pass strings and ints between. They get automatically marshalled as appropriate (e.g. a managed string goes to BSTR*).

I now have added a new method to my COM interface which returns a `List<String>`. I figured the method type generated would return  <s>an array of BSTR* (BSTR**) and a count</s>  a SAFEARRAY, however when I look at the IDL (using oleview), this interface method doesn't even appear. I'm guessing the COM framework isn't sure what a `List<String>` looks like, so what are my options here? Just using string[]?

I'm not using C++/CX, and I cannot.

Thanks

Comment: I now use string[]. That what you meant? Could you elaborate what you meant by using a variant? I understand I get a variant within the safearray but do you mean declare the type as a variant in the managed code. COM noob here.

Comment: i'm passing from c# to c++. The IDL/spec is generated automatically for me from the interface attributes in c#

Comment: My mistake.  Try returning just `string[]`.  `List` might be too _high fidelity_ for COM.  The former should be converted to `SAFEARRAY` or perhaps a `VARIANT` by .NET

Comment: yeah, I used a string[] in the end. I've made it so use lists internally inside my managed class library. Then at my COM wrapper I call .ToArray(). In my native code I use psaMyComInterface->rgsabound[0].cElements to get the element count (I know it's 1 dimension) and extract the elements using SafeArrayGetElement. It works, but I'd like to know if what I'm doing is frowned upon (or what's best practice in general)

Comment: It's perfectly fine.  In this instance .NET has to learn to play by COM's rules and know that whilst some things are automatically converted (like `string` to BSTR) others are not (`List<>`)